# Low cost satellite (cubesat) tracking station

Tags: satellites

To track and receive some data from satellites, or should I say cubesats - which are kind of popular these days, which is the minimum investment? What's cheapest/easiest satellite to begin with? Besides a laptop which equipment do I need?

Comment: What did you find already? Did you have a look at projects like [SatNOGS](https://satnogs.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

With as little as about £20 you can get going. For a starter you can try to listen to the CW beacons of cubesats like UKube-1. They are in good old morse code and usually transmitting in the 2m amateur band. I built the cheapest tracking yagi out of an old venetian blind and used an RTL-SDR dongle as the receiver.
Here are two articles I wrote about the subject:
[Tracking UKube-1](http://www.spaceportscotland.org/news.asp?intent=viewstory&newsid=63498) 
[Low budget satellite tracking](http://www.spaceportscotland.org/index.asp?pageid=571655)

Comment: We generally prefer that you include more than just a link or two to answer questions like this, in case something happens to the linked site where it no longer functions. It's been know to happen, even on very reputable sites.